# trying to use subquery but subquery returns more than one row with qualifiers

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm writing a query to generate a graph based on 7 day rolling stats. The `newpost` and `closedpost` work all fine, but i'm getting `subquery returns more than one row` when i try to setup a qualifier such as `WHERE closed IS NOT NULL AND (sent = 0 OR sent =1) AND created >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY  GROUP BY  DATE(created))` to display `solvedpost`. I'm not sure how to go about making this work. Any help would be appriciated

my query:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(created) newpostdate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT created) newpost,
    COUNT(DISTINCT closed) closedpost,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(DISTINCT closed)
        FROM
            tickets
        WHERE
            closed IS NOT NULL
                AND (sent = 0 OR sent = 1)
                AND created >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
        GROUP BY DATE(created)) solvedpost
FROM
    tickets
WHERE
    created >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(created);
```

Comment: query with `GROUP BY DATE(created)` return count() for each day. i.e several rows. change condition to get only one row

Comment: May I suggest you send some dummy data in the same structure your table uses and the result you expect from a query? The question like it is, I can only tell you will need to give an alias to tickets outside and another alias for tickets inside the subquery and relate both collections somehow - and **if** a subquery is really the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(created) newpostdate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT created) newpost,
    COUNT(DISTINCT closed) closedpost,
    COUNT(DISTINCT
        CASE WHEN closed IS NOT NULL AND (sent = 0 OR sent = 1)
        THEN closed END
    ) solvedpost
FROM
    tickets
WHERE
    created >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(created);
```

You don't even need the `closed IS NOT NULL` condition, because NULLs just wan't be counted.

This is based on your original query. But i think you shouldn't use `DISTINCT`. If you decide not to use `DISTICT` your query could be:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(created) newpostdate,
    COUNT(created) newpost,
    COUNT(closed) closedpost,
    SUM(closed IS NOT NULL AND (sent = 0 OR sent = 1)) solvedpost
FROM
    tickets
WHERE
    created >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(created);
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for and your correct about distinct. This is an advance query for me and i'm trying to dig further into the use of mysql. I didn't even know case was a thing thank you =)